# Custom Module blank page

Tags: magento-1.9

I just created a module, but when I try to access the page is blank, could someone help me? follow my config.xml and adminhtml.xml

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Zeep_Configuracao>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Zeep_Configuracao>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <configuracao>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Zeep_Configuracao</module>
                    <frontName>configuracao</frontName>
                </args>
            </configuracao>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <configuracao>
                    <file>configuracao.xml</file>
                </configuracao>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <configuracao>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Zeep_Configuracao</module>
                    <frontName>configuracao</frontName>
                </args>
            </configuracao>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    <global>
        <models>
            <configuracao>
                <class>Zeep_Configuracao_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>configuracao_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </configuracao>
            <configuracao_mysql4>
                <class>Zeep_Configuracao_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <configuracao>
                        <table>configuracao</table>
                    </configuracao>
                </entities>
            </configuracao_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <configuracao_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Zeep_Configuracao</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </configuracao_setup>
            <configuracao_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </configuracao_write>
            <configuracao_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </configuracao_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <configuracao>
                <class>Zeep_Configuracao_Block</class>
            </configuracao>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <configuracao>
                <class>Zeep_Configuracao_Helper</class>
            </configuracao>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

and my adminhtml.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <configuracao module="configuracao">
            <title>Zeepi Configuração</title>
            <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
            <children>
                <first_menu_child module="configuracao">
                    <title>Banner Principal</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>configuracao/adminhtml_configuracao</action>
                </first_menu_child>
                <second_menu_child module="configuracao">
                    <title>Banner Principal 2</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>configuracao/adminhtml_configuracao</action>
                </second_menu_child>
            </children>
        </configuracao>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <Zeep_Configuracao>
                        <title>Configuracao Module</title>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        <children>
                             <first_menu_child module="configuracao">
                                <title>Banner Principal</title>
                                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                <action>configuracao/adminhtml_configuracao</action>
                            </first_menu_child>
                            <second_menu_child module="configuracao">
                                <title>Banner Principal 2</title>
                                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                                <action>configuracao/adminhtml_configuracao</action>
                            </second_menu_child>
                        </children>
                    </Zeep_Configuracao>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
            <updates>
                <configuracao>
                    <file>configuracao.xml</file>
                </configuracao>
            </updates>
        </layout>
</config>
```

Comment: Please add more specific to your needs. like for what is your purpose to Extention and where you can display it.

Comment: OK! i go edit my post.

Comment: ok add more details ok